# Moveit trajectory only providing translation, not velocity or acceleration

Tags: moveit

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have just started using moveit and have implemented the multi-degree of freedom joint type described here https://www.wilselby.com/research/ros-integration/3d-mapping-navigation/. Though when I generate a trajectory it currently only publishes the transforms and not the velocities or accelerations. I assume this is something moveit can produce? Is this a flag in my launch file? or is it my lack of understanding of the custom join?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/264957/moveit-trajectory-only-providing-translation,-not-velocity-or-acceleration/) by [tonka46](https://answers.ros.org/users/30744/tonka46/) on ROS Answers with karma: 46 on 2017-06-27

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-06-28**:
I'm not sure, but it could be that the 'parameterisation step' (using the IPTP) is not run for multi-dof trajectories. Unfortunately I cannot offer you more assistance than this at the moment, but it should give you a starting point.

**Comment by [tonka46](https://answers.ros.org/users/30744/tonka46/) on 2017-06-28**:
Thanks!
This will give me a start point I will have a look in the next few day.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-06-29**:
I was about to suggest posting an issue over at `ros-planning/moveit/issues`, but I see you already posted one: [ros-planning/moveit#39](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/issues/539).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have resolved this for my needs by adding

in robot_trajectory.cpp

at line 284ish

```
        if (waypoints_[i]->hasVelocities()){
        const std::vector<std::string> names =  mdof[j]->getVariableNames();
        const double* velocities =  waypoints_[i]->getJointVelocities(mdof[j]);
         geometry_msgs::Twist point_velocity;
        for(std::size_t ii = 0; ii < names.size(); ++ii){
          if(names[ii].find("/x") != std::string::npos)
          {
            ROS_INFO_STREAM("multi dof joint x velocity: "<<velocities[ii]);
            point_velocity.linear.x = velocities[ii];
          }
          else if(names[ii].find("/y") != std::string::npos)
          {
            ROS_INFO_STREAM("multi dof joint y velocity: "<<velocities[ii]);
            point_velocity.linear.y = velocities[ii];
          }
          else if(names[ii].find("/z") != std::string::npos)
          {
            ROS_INFO_STREAM("multi dof joint z velocity: "<<velocities[ii]);
            point_velocity.linear.z = velocities[ii];
          }
          else if(names[ii].find("/theta") != std::string::npos)
          {
            ROS_INFO_STREAM("multi dof joint theta velocity: "<<velocities[ii]);
            point_velocity.angular.z = velocities[ii];
          }
          else
          {
            ROS_INFO_STREAM("velocity name: "<<names[ii]);
          }
        }
        trajectory.multi_dof_joint_trajectory.points[i].velocities.push_back(point_velocity);
       }
```

in trajectory_execution_manager.cpp

at line 863

```
        if (!trajectory.multi_dof_joint_trajectory.points[j].velocities.empty())
        {
          parts[i].multi_dof_joint_trajectory.points[j].velocities.resize(bijection.size());

          parts[i].multi_dof_joint_trajectory.points[j].velocities[0].linear.x =
            trajectory.multi_dof_joint_trajectory.points[j].velocities[0].linear.x * execution_velocity_scaling_;

          parts[i].multi_dof_joint_trajectory.points[j].velocities[0].linear.y =
            trajectory.multi_dof_joint_trajectory.points[j].velocities[0].linear.y * execution_velocity_scaling_;

          parts[i].multi_dof_joint_trajectory.points[j].velocities[0].linear.z =
            trajectory.multi_dof_joint_trajectory.points[j].velocities[0].linear.z * execution_velocity_scaling_;

          parts[i].multi_dof_joint_trajectory.points[j].velocities[0].angular.x =
            trajectory.multi_dof_joint_trajectory.points[j].velocities[0].angular.x * execution_velocity_scaling_;

          parts[i].multi_dof_joint_trajectory.points[j].velocities[0].angular.y =
            trajectory.multi_dof_joint_trajectory.points[j].velocities[0].angular.y * execution_velocity_scaling_;

          parts[i].multi_dof_joint_trajectory.points[j].velocities[0].angular.z =
            trajectory.multi_dof_joint_trajectory.points[j].velocities[0].angular.z * execution_velocity_scaling_;
        }
```

---

Originally posted by [tonka46](https://answers.ros.org/users/30744/tonka46/) with karma: 46 on 2017-07-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2017-12-09**:
Update: [Improvement](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/pull/555) for this is merged.